# const reference to non-const object

Tags: c++, reference

In the following, would there be a temporary object created before const reference is used to a non-const object?

```
const int y = 2000;
const int &s = y // ok, const reference to const object.

int x = 1000;
const int &r = x; // any temporary copy here?
```

If no then, how does this work?

```
   const int z = 3000;
   int &t = z // ok, why can't you do this?
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.

A reference is simply an alias for an existing object.  `const` is enforced by the compiler; it simply checks that you don't attempt to modify the object through the reference `r`.<sup>*</sup>  This doesn't require a copy to be created.

Given that `const` is merely an instruction to the compiler to enforce "read-only", then it should be immediately obvious why your final example doesn't compile.  `const` would be pointless if you could trivially circumvent it by taking a non-`const` ref to a `const` object.

<sub>* Of course, you are still free to modify the object via `x`.  Any changes will also be visible via `r`, because they refer to the same object.</sub>

Comment: In particular, the value of `r` can change, even though it is declared `const`.

Comment: Usually, compilers implement the reference with a simple pointer.

Comment: @quant_dev Given OP's sample, the source code that mentions `x` and source code that mentions `r` are compiled to identical machine code. No pointers involved (on all compilers I've seen). Not that it's relevant anyway.

Comment: @Cubbi: this all depends on the context, whenever the compiler can just *alias* the names, it will do so, but if the reference is passed to a function or stored in a type, etc. the compiler must store a reference to the object, and that is usually done with pointers.

Answer (score 7):

In

```
int x = 1000;
const int &r = x;
```

the right-hand side is an *lvalue* and the type of `x` is the same as the type of the reference (ignoring cv-qualifications). Under these circumstances the reference is attached directly to `x`, no temporary is created.

As for "how does this work"... I don't understand what prompted your question. It just works in the most straighforward way: the reference is attached directly to `x`. Nothing more to it.

You can't do

```
const int z = 3000;
int &t = z;
```

because it immediately violates the rules of const-correctness.

Comment: so what you are saying is that there is no implicit conversion taking place  on x "from int to const int " during reference binding is that right? If yes can you provide link to the standard of the statement which proves your point..

Comment: @sparsh goyal: Process of reference initialization is described in 9.4.4/5 (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5). This situation immediately falls under 5.1 and  5.1.1. No conversion "from int to const int" is involved there.

Answer (score 3):

The understanding on the Reference (&) answers this question..

Reference is just an alias to the variable that it is assigned to it..

And const is a constraint imposed by the compiler to the variable that is declared as const

```
int x = 1000;
const int &r = x;
```

In this case, its a const reference to a non const variable. So you cannot change the data of x with reference variable r(just acts a read only).. yet you can still change the data x by modifying x

```
const int z = 3000;
int &t = z
```

In this case, non const reference to const member which is meaningless. You are saying reference can allow you to edit a const member(which is never possible)..

So if you want to create a reference for a const member, it has to be like the first case you mentioned

```
const int z = 3000;
const int &t = z;
```