# How can you assign a const reference to a non const variable?

Tags: c++

Consider following code, onData callback invoked and then I assign the const reference to a variable. I want to understand how it works. I was told you can't modify const references but here it looks like you can by assigning to a non-const variable.

```
void onData(const evpp::TCPConnPtr &socket) {
   evpp::TCPConnPtr connection = socket;
}
```

In real world application, I assign this to Object Instance's member variable.

Comment: why not? Why do you think the code would modify the `socket` ?

Comment: where exactly you think ```socket``` is modified, here as you were told, object passed by const reference is not modified :)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Currently, it doesn't modify the socket. I just want to understand how it works.. It's confusing..

Comment: its similar to `const int x = 42; int y = x; y = 0;`

Comment: You're not assigning the reference but the value of the referenced object, and assigning *from* a const thing is fine.

Comment: @molbdnilo Does this creates a copy? If so, how can I avoid it specially when assigning to instance member variables. I'm confused on perf implications too.

Comment: This might give you the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406980/const-reference-to-non-const-object/24384750

Comment: Yes, it creates a copy. Why do you think that has any noticable impact on performance? It's a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @jeffbRTC Where is there any assignment to an instance member variable in your question?

Comment: @jeffbRTC don't worry about performance until you have an actual performance issue. `connection = socket` is a call to [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) of `evpp::TCPConnPtr` which, as you can see in the ref, uses either a copy, or a const reference, therefore promising not to change the arguments or only change a copy

Comment: @SyedMohibUddin No, that seems to be about something totally different or opposite to this.

Comment: @underscore_d I didn't add instance stuff here because I wanted to keep it minimal

Comment: @gkhaos is there way I could make it const? I don't know to explain this very well to you. Maybe Is there way I could avoid the copy at all? I'm assigning to instance member variable.

Comment: @jeffbRTC make sure you understand what pointers are, how references fit in, and why you should never use raw pointers in C++, and what the [Rule of 4 (and a half)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762560/9233560) is. If you are curious about how you can help your compiler to copy less the keyword is [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). However, to use these things well in projects [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) is key.

Comment: @gkhaos I don't use raw pointers at all. I always use references but this one was confusing because for some some reason..

Comment: @gkhaos Thanks for the links. I am going to research them asap.

Comment: @jeffbRTC IMHO you should be familiar with using pointers (but never use them). If you understand pointer and pointer arithmetic lots of things become obviously clear. E.g. a reference is basically a const pointer without the need of dereferencing. A reference-to-const basically is a const pointer-to-const...

Comment: @gkhaos Yes, I used raw pointers in past also I know references does dereferencing under hood but my brain get mad or what.. I don't know how to explain this to you. It also happens when I look at numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, a reference is just an alias to the referenced object. When a reference is `const` it means you may not modify the object via that reference (the object can be modified via other means, this distinction is important, especially with multithreading). Copying a `const` reference is like copying the referenced object:

```
 std::string x = "foo";
 const std::string& x_const_ref = x;  // constant reference to x
                                      // x can be modifed but not via x_const_ref
 //x_const_ref = "moo";  // ERROR !
 x = "bar";              // OK !
 std::string y = x;                   // y is initialized with a copy of x
 std::string z = x_const_ref;         // z is initialized with a copy of x
```

`y` and `z` will both hold the string `"bar"`, though `x` is not modified in the last two lines. And if `TCPConnPtr` has no weird copy constructor then thats basically also what happens in your code (if it does try to modify `socket` you would get a compiler error).

Comment: Numbers confusing me because I have Dyscalculia. Mind to use a `std::string`?

Comment: @jeffbRTC heard about it, but never actually met someone. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I got the concept now. Wonder if there a way to avoid the copy but I'm not sure what the correct type I should use in that case ...

Comment: @jeffbRTC the `Ptr` sufffix suggests that `TCPConnPtr` is just a pointer and if thats the case you should not worry about making one copy. You could even pass it by value

Comment: I know that but I asking in general sense just my intellectual curiosity.

Comment: @jeffbRTC also in general there is no point in passing a pointer as `const` reference :)

Comment: No I was asking you not expecting in pointer sense. ..